# Python running wrong version of selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, pip

I'm trying to update my version of Selenium to the current version (3.0.1).  Typing "sudo easy_install selenium" results in

```
Best match: selenium 3.0.1
Adding selenium 3.0.1 to easy-install.pth file
Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

which seems correct.

However, when I run python and type `import selenium" followed by help ( selenium )`, I see

```
DATA
    __version__ = '2.53.6'    
VERSION
    2.53.6
```

Obviously, that's an older version.

Running `pip install -U selenium` results in the following:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Running the command `pip show selenium` yields the following:

```
Name: selenium
Version: 3.0.1
Summary: Python bindings for Selenium
Home-page: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

I can only assume that somehow I've got the right version of selenium in one spot and the wrong version wherever python's looking.  So how do I tell python to cut it out and look where it should?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try uninstalling selenium and then reinstall it?

```
   pip uninstall selenium
   pip install selenium
```